# Is it possible to derive(RustcEncodable) for part of struct?

Tags: rust

I have a struct like:

```
struct S {
    data: i32,
    fun: Box<Fn()>,
}
```

and would like to serialize the data part using an encoder. To do that I use rustc_serialize and derive its traits like

```
#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct S {
    data: i32,
    fun: Box<Fn()>,
}
```

The problem is that `fun` can't be serialized as it's a function. This is fine as I only want to serialize the plain `data` field. Is there a way to do that?

The `data` field in my real use case is also a struct which can also have a `Fn` so I can't simply split the struct into two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no". The rustc-serialize crate <sup>1</sup> does not provide that level of control on the automated implementations of traits like `Decodable` or `Encodable`.

To do this, you would need to implement them yourself:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::{Encodable, Encoder};
use rustc_serialize::json;

struct S {
    data: i32,
    fun: Box<Fn()>,
}

impl Encodable for S {
    fn encode<S: Encoder>(&self, s: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error> {
        s.emit_struct("S", 1, |s| {
            s.emit_struct_field("data", 0, |s| {
                s.emit_i32(self.data)
            })
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let thing = S { data: 42, fun: Box::new(|| println!("I am a function")) };
    let json = json::encode(&thing).expect("Couldn't encode");
    println!("{}", json);
    (thing.fun)();
}
```

If you aren't tied to rustc-serialize, you may be interested in [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) which offers the `#[serde(skip_serializing)]` and `#[serde(skip_deserializing)]` annotations.

---

**1**: Technically, `#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]` is provided *by the compiler*. This is why it has the `Rustc` prefix. It's also an ugly wart that wants to be removed but is waiting for stable support of compiler plugins.

Answer (score 3):

[Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288282/is-it-possible-to-deriverustcencodable-for-part-of-struct/37300116#37300116) gives the RustcEncodable solution. For completeness, here is the equivalent [Serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) code:

```
#![feature(custom_derive, plugin)]
#![plugin(serde_macros)]

extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct S {
    data: i32,
    #[serde(skip_serializing, skip_deserializing, default="empty_fun")]
    fun: Box<Fn()>,
}

fn empty_fun() -> Box<Fn()> {
    Box::new(|| {})
}

fn main() {
    let s = S { data: 42, fun: Box::new(|| println!("I am a function")) };

    // prints {"data":42}
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap());
}
```

The `skip_serializing` attribute means ignore the field when serializing the struct. Similarly, the `skip_deserializing` attribute means ignore the field when deserializing.

The `default` attribute gives the value to use for the field when deserializing. Fields that implement [`std::default::Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) do not need this as Serde is able to use the value of `Default::default()`.